# if, else if statement not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everything works fine until I get to the second `else if` when both divs are activated. For some reason, only `#project-wrapper` gets the class removed. Did I write the second `else if` wrong?

```
$('.site-title a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#project-wrapper').hasClass('activated')){
        $('#project-wrapper').removeClass('activated').css('max-height', '');
    }
    else if($('#contact-me').hasClass('activated')){
        $('#contact-me').removeClass('activated');
    }
    else if( ($('#project-wrapper').hasClass('activated')) && ($('#contact-me').hasClass('activated')) ){
        $('#contact-me').removeClass('activated');
        $('#project-wrapper').removeClass('activated');
    }
    else {
    }

});
```

Comment: If "project-wrapper" has the class "activated", then the first `if` test would succeed. Once that's happened, the whole list of `else` clauses will be skipped. The test you've got in the last `else if` should be the **first** test you do.

Comment: When you are doing various checks like this, always try to go from the most specific scenario to the most general. In other words, in this case do the test for both being activated first.

Comment: @Rhumborl Thank you. I'm learning day by day! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the "both" condition first, else that condition will never be checked:

```
if( $('#project-wrapper').hasClass('activated') && $('#contact-me').hasClass('activated') ) {
  $('#contact-me, #project-wrapper').removeClass('activated');
}
else if($('#project-wrapper').hasClass('activated')){
  $('#project-wrapper').removeClass('activated').css('max-height', '');
}
else if($('#contact-me').hasClass('activated')){
  $('#contact-me').removeClass('activated');
}
else {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to switch the if staments around because the 2nd else if will never get hit

```
$('.site-title a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if( ($('#project-wrapper').hasClass('activated')) && ($('#contact-me').hasClass('activated')) ){
        $('#project-wrapper').removeClass('activated').css('max-height', '');
    }
    else if($('#contact-me').hasClass('activated')){
        $('#contact-me').removeClass('activated');
    }
    else if($('#project-wrapper').hasClass('activated')){
        $('#contact-me').removeClass('activated');
        $('#project-wrapper').removeClass('activated');
    }
    else {
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the 'else' parts and keep all conditions in seperate 'if'. That should work

Comment: but this implementation requires the compiler to check each if statement and waste resources (yes this would work, but its not efficient)

Comment: This wouldn't work, since the third 'if' would never be true. ever. After the first two 'if's, the two elements are no longer 'activated'...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.site-title a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if( ($('#project-wrapper').hasClass('activated')) && ($('#contact-me').hasClass('activated')) ){
        $('#contact-me').removeClass('activated');
        $('#project-wrapper').removeClass('activated');
    }
    if($('#project-wrapper').hasClass('activated')){
        $('#project-wrapper').removeClass('activated').css('max-height', '');
    }
    if($('#contact-me').hasClass('activated')){
        $('#contact-me').removeClass('activated');
    }
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. The third 'if' would never happen because if any of the elements is 'activated', the first two 'if's would remove the 'activated' class, and then the third 'if' would never be 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the second 'else-if' statement will **NEVER** be reached since it requires that **BOTH** elements will have the class 'activated', and if that's the case, then the **FIRST** 'if' will kick in, and nothing else will happen.... (all of the 'else if' statements...)